# unable to create css table if useless divs are in place

Tags: html, css

I am having some foreign html and would like to format it with a css table. Unfortunately, the html contains an additional div between the "tabular-row-divs" and the "tabular-cell-divs".

Example:
html:

```
<div class="tabular">
  <div class="useless">
    <div class="tabular-row">
      <label class="tabular-cell">AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA</label>
      <label class="tabular-cell">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="entry.3.single" value="" class="tabular-cell" id="entry_3">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabular-row">
    <div class="tabular-cell">
      something
    </div>
    <div class="tabular-cell">
      display: table-celllllllllllllllllllll;
    </div>
    <div class="tabular-cell">
      cellllllllllllllllllll 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current css:

```
div .tabular {display: table;  padding: 5px;}
div .tabular-row {display: table-row;}
div .tabular-cell {display: table-cell; padding: 5px;  }
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to make the table work because of the div with the class "useless". I am also not able to find a solution via google, although I think it is trivial. Can you help me?

David

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
div> div>  .tabular {display: table;  padding: 5px;}
div> div>  .tabular-row {display: table-row;}
div> div>  .tabular-cell {display: table-cell; padding: 5px;  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when you sort out a few problems

1. you need to close the space between the `div` and the class name in the css.  `div .tabular` should be `div.tabular`, etc.
2. you are adding `display:table-cell` to `label` and `input` elements.  Remove the `class` there and wrap `div`s around each element
3. you also had one extra closing `</div>` which I removed

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/Gy3W4/3/

Comment: Unfortunately, your solutions do not solve my problem. But somehow, css doesn't seem to have a solution to fix my problem. First, I thought I can bypass it by setting the display of .useless to table-row-group. But than I saw, that I have another useless div in my usecase. Which is the form of the google form iframe.
I guess, I need to find a solution with javascript or without a css table.